# Cannot wrie header FFMPEG

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, streaming

I'm working on a Project with FFMPEg, but somehow i cannot creae any media file. I've set the Parameters, codec etc. but when i call avformat_write_header the app just stops working.
Here's my code:

```
AVOutputFormat *fmt;
AVCodecContext *codecctx;
AVFormatContext *fmtctx;
fmt=av_guess_format(NULL,filename,NULL);
    AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(fmt->video_codec);
codecctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
codecctx->codec_id = fmt->video_codec;
codecctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
codecctx->gop_size = 12;
codecctx->bit_rate = WIDTH*HEIGHT*4;
codecctx->width = WIDTH;
codecctx->height = HEIGHT;
codecctx->time_base.den = 2;  
codecctx->time_base.num =1;
//codecctx->time_base =(AVRational){1,FPS};
codecctx->max_b_frames=1;
codecctx->pix_fmt= STREAM_PIX_FMT;
fmtctx = avformat_alloc_context();
fmtctx->oformat = fmt;
fmtctx->video_codec_id = fmt->video_codec;
avcodec_open2(codecctx, codec, NULL);
    AVStream *VideoStream = avformat_new_stream(fmtctx,codec);  
avformat_write_header(fmtctx,NULL);
```

Comment: When you say your application stops working what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Thanks, the Problem is i fogot to cal avio_open. Now I'm trying to add a png Image to the stream, but don't know how to convert ti to an useable Frame. Can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 0):

The main API functions for muxing are avformat_write_header() for writing the file header, av_write_frame() / av_interleaved_write_frame() for writing the packets and av_write_trailer() for finalizing the file.

check this link

http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__encoding.html#details